# React-Redux action is not dispatched properly?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have following Action:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export function getAPIData(id)
{
    return (dispatch) =>
    {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/' + id)
        .then(res =>
        {
            dispatch(
            {
                type: 'DONE',
                payload: res.data
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Then in my Component I`m dispatching the action:

```
  componentDidMount()
  {
    this.props.dispatch(getAPIData());
  }
```

And then:

```
function mapStateToProps(state)
{
  console.log(state);
  return { 
    data: state.result
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Rows);
```

In console, when I try to find the payload, it says what is bellow.

> function()
>
> arguments: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be
> accessed in this context.
>
> caller: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be
> accessed in this context.
>
> length: 1
>
> name: ""

Where is problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can u share the reducer that you have defined for the action type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to dispatch an action you need to provide `mapDispatchToProps` .

First import your action

```
import { getAPIData } from "../store/actions/getAPIData";
```

then build `mapDispatchToProps`

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
   getAPIData: (props = null) => {
     dispatch(getAPIData(props));
  },
 };
};
```

add this alongside `mapStateToProps`

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps , mapDispatchToProps)(Rows);
```

now you can call the action like this

```
 componentDidMount()
 {
   this.props.getAPIData();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, now it doesnt show that error. But my variable is now undefined (variable, where should be stored the json result)

Comment: please show us your reducer which handles the case `DONE`